# Translating code from Objective-C to Swift issues

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsurl, nsdocumentdirectory

In my app I want to add the following Objective-C code in Swift,

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                               inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

My attempt has quite a few issues, aside from the syntax not being correct it seems that NSDocumentDirectory and NSUserDomainMask don't exist in Swift.

```
var applicationDocumentsDirectory : NSURL {

    return NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSDocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSUserDomainMask.lastObject)
}
```

The reason I'm using this computed property is that I need to pass an output URL to this camera framework I'm using as such...

```
        // start recording
        NSURL *outputURL = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                             URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test1"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"];
        [self.camera startRecordingWithOutputUrl:outputURL];
```

Thank you for the help like always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last
```